# SmackAndroid.init() throws IllegalStateException: "Could not init static class blocks"

Tags: android, asmack

I'm starting out with asmack for Android to compliment a Java instant messenging application I have already built. After a while with getting ClassNotFound Exceptions and errors with locating my server (despite the addresses and ports being correct) I read about the SmackAndroid call that was recommended to initialise the static classes.
I coded it as follows:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SmackAndroid asmk = SmackAndroid.init(context);
```

I addded these lines of code to my application before any XMPP connection had been established but it gives me a new error entirely that I cannot solve.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{cit.jordan.portablechatter/cit.jordan.portablechatter.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not init static class blocks`

I am using the asmack 0.8.2 jar for android 17 found here: http://asmack.freakempire.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown at [InitStaticCode.java:48](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/static-src/custom/org/jivesoftware/smackx/InitStaticCode.java#L48) and I got similar report from another user. I always wonder why it works for most users but a few.

You could try to remove the `getClass()` call in [InitStaticCode.java:34](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/static-src/custom/org/jivesoftware/smackx/InitStaticCode.java#L34) and see if it works. Another idea, if you are unable to modify and build aSmack for yourself, would be to change the type of context you are using as parameter: Experiment with `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext`. Maybe this helps.

I have entered this as [aSmack's issue # 33](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/issues/33). Maybe I find the time to fix it this weekend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried using different application contexts, all provide the same error. I tried some other methods to no avail.
Is there any workaround for the SmackAndroid call? Would it be possible to initialise these classes manually in the program?

Comment: No, but given the fact that aSmack is open source you can copy the code and try InitStaticCode without `getClass()`. Some users are reporting that this fixes the problem for them.

Comment: It took a while but I tried your suggestions today and I managed to skirt around the issue. The recommended AndroidConnectionConfiguration call repeatedly gave me DNS errors so I had to use the standard ConnectionConfiguration call. Currently trying to figure out why the client is showing in the server's active client sessions but is marked as offline and cannot interact with other clients. It's probably a different issue althogether though.

Comment: And which suggestion helped you fixing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem.
Then i found a solution which is as below.

first download the following jar
[latest asmack jar](http://asmack.freakempire.de/0.8.2/asmack-android-17-0.8.2.jar)

```
SmackAndroid.init(context);
AndroidConnectionConfiguration mAndroidConnectionConfiguration=new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(host, port);
```

I think this will solve your connection issue.
Above method work for me so i hope it will be helpful to you.